# How do I write a formula using both a picklist and a checkbox?

Tags: formula, picklist

I've added a picklist field "Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c" with the choices being "Yes" or "No".  There is a checkbox field "Lease_Assignment_Received__c" that I will also use.  This field has been used for a few years so I can't change the field type.  I'm trying to write a formula for a third field (Text) that will give me "NA" if Lease/Lease Assign Applicable is "No" and "Checked or Yes/Unchecked or No" as applicable.  Below is the formula I've tried and the error message I received.  I'm guessing there is an issue with converting a checkbox field to text.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

IF(ISPICKVAL(Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c, “Yes”),  TEXT(Lease_Assignment_Received__c), “NA”)
Error: Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to write this. You'll need a logical condition test for the checkbox field rather than `TEXT()`.

In this example, the `AND()` function is used to make sure all of those conditions are true. If they're all true, it displays "Yes", otherwise "NA".

```
IF (
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c, "Yes" ),
        Lease_Assignment_Received__c
    ),
    "Yes",
    "NA"
)
```

Update to address the comment: another IF statement is needed to evaluate the second condition.

```
IF (
    ISPICKVAL( Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c, "Yes" ),
    IF ( Lease_Assignment_Received__c, "Yes", "No" ),
    "NA"
)
```

Comment: If Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c is "Yes", but  Lease_Assignment_Received__c is not checked, I'm getting "NA".  In that case, I'd like to get "No".  How can I make that happen?  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  I've struggled with this project off and on for weeks.  Because of your help I can finally finish this.  Thanks!